# Screenshot and Editing on OS X

Tags: osx, screenshot

Looking for a screenshot tool with the following functions

- works on OSX
- start up quickly
- able to take screenshot with hotkey
- able to continuous take screenshot at predefined interval (eg. 1 every 5 sec)
- able to put the screenshots into a default or predefined folder
- able to do basic editing, including

  - define a cropping area that can apply to all screenshots in the folder
  - masking function for sensitive data
  - draw basic boxes, circles, arrows
  - enter text in a textbox
- prefer free/open source
- paid version should be around $20

Answer (score 1):

This [Tool](http://joshparnham.com/projects/shotbox/) came after you have take a screenshot. So you can normaly use the Mac bundled Grab utility and than automatically opened this tool where you can edit the picture.
[image: ShotBox]
I don't know if this the right one.

Comment: Seems the right one but it's no longer available